# Understrap/Bootstrap: .row-equal-height not working for equal height columns?

Tags: row, height, equals

I'm trying to make 3 columns in a row equal height. I used `row-equal-height`, but nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-lg-4 content-block">
    <img src="../wp-content/themes/understrap-child/img/Assisted-Living.jpeg" />
    <div>
      <h2>Assisted Living</h2>
      <img class="icon" src="../wp-content/themes/understrap-child/img/icons/assisted-living.png" />
       Bridging the gap between seniors needing some help and being unable to care for themselves is the purpose of assisted living facilities...
...
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 content-block">
    <img src="../wp-content/themes/understrap-child/img/Memory-Care.jpeg" />
    <div>
      <h2>Memory Care</h2>
      <img class="icon" src="../wp-content/themes/understrap-child/img/icons/memory-care.png" />
       Enhancing the life of seniors with memory impairment (due to Alzheimer’s, dementia, or aging) is to specifically enhance the dignity and well-being of each resident...
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 content-block">
    <img src="../wp-content/themes/understrap-child/img/Independent-Living.jpeg" />
    <div>
      <h2>Independent Living</h2>
      <img class="icon" src="../wp-content/themes/understrap-child/img/icons/independent-living.png" />
     Engaging in a fulfilling lifestyle is so much more than where you live...
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the website in progress: https://ciminocarestg.wpengine.com/

It's the column of 3 under the hero (Assisted Living, Memory Care, and Independent Living) that I want to make equal height.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the visuals.

Your `row-eq-height` is working, but is just so happens that your content, within each column, is inside a nested child div element that is not impacted by `row-eq-height`.

For a quick and easy way to solve the issue, especially if your content is finalized, then add this CSS rule to your site...

```
.home .content-block div {
  min-height:425px;
}
```

In the future, do either of the following:

1. If the content in any of your 3 columns expands, just simply adjust that `min-height` value.
2. If you don't want to depend on this technique, then pull out the nested divs that are in each column, so that the content is only 1 level deep, not 2.

In either case, UnderStrap is still an excellent choice for a theme and utilizing BootStrap.